How do I automatically add my service registration to the di container
I want to automate adding services to di container. Here in my ServiceRegistration class:
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductDetailService, ProductDetailService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductImageService, ProductImageService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
...

I don't want to add like this, I want to mark each of my service classes with an attribute and find this class and find the interface that the class I found implements and add it to di container automatically. How do I do this? Or do you have a better solution?
I don't want to add my services manually, I want to do it automatically

You can use Reflection:
var components =
    from type in typeof(CategoryService).Assembly.GetTypes()
    where type.Name.EndsWith("Service")
    where !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsGenenicTypeDefinition
    where type.GetInterfaces().Count() == 1
    select { Service = type.GetInterfaces().Single(), Implementation = type };

foreach (var component in components)
{
    services.AddScoped(component.Service, component.Implementation);
}

There are also extensions to MS.DI available that can simplify this task, such as Scrutor.

thank you so mych Steven. I have one more question; wouldn't using reflection cost me a lot here? Would it be right to create a SourceGenerator instead? I created a source generator but it doesn't give me the necessary response during compilation. Thank you for your answer.

"wouldn't using reflection cost me a lot here?" A lot of what?

I need to use it in a big project. Doesn't reflection cause security vulnerabilities, performance issues, and more memory usage? Generating the code statically at compile time with the source generator seemed better to me, but I'd like to get your opinion.

"Doesn't reflection cause security vulnerabilities" - No, it doesn't.

"performance issues" You'll have to measure that whether that holds in your case, but be careful to measure the complete startup time difference between Explicit Register and this (Reflection-base) Auto-Registration. While there is certainly overhead, the overhead is typically smaller than you think.

"more memory usage". At the time the objects are queried using reflection, there will be temporarily more use of memory, but there is no difference in memory use after the startup phase. In case in doubt: do measure.

"Generating the code statically at compile time with the source generator seemed better to me". Generating this code using a Code Generator is certainly possible, would sometimes lead to faster startups, but you'll loose flexibility opposed to taking this dynamic runtime-based way of registering things. Also note that mature DI Containers in .NET use this Reflection-based approach for almost two decades, while this compile-time code generation to to register dependencies is fairly new.

While this is a good answer, I think you should probably mention some of the pitfalls too. Like reflections stops you being able to use AOT. But bigger issues like this would fail if any of the services implement more than one interface, or if the services reside in multiple assemblies.

@DavidG, I think you just mentioned AOT :-). There are of course this shown example is very limited. How to write your Auto-Registration queries, however, is highly dependent on the conventions the application applies. That context is completely missing from the question. The question is very broad, and my resulting answer, therefore, is as well. The idea is to give the OP an idea how to tackle this and extend upon needs. Changing this to support multiple interfaces and multiple assemblies shouldn't be difficult for an experienced C# developer.

Sure, but you provided no context in your answer so people will blindly come in and not have any idea why they may not want to do things this way. If I had written this answer, I may have started with "Don't do it this way unless you really know what you are doing and have good practices in place". As for me adding the AOT line, we all know that comments are pretty ephemeral around here and could go away at any time, let alone the fact most people don't read them in the first place.

@DavidG, point taken. I typically do provide more context in my answers here on SO. If you post your own answer, I'll sure upvote it - as I often do with your answers.
